# Paragraph module won't install or uninstall

Tags: 8

I installed the paragraph module from https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs specifically the dev version `8.x-1.x-dev   tar.gz (118.62 KB) | zip (210.83 KB)    2017-Jun-28` it installed ok but now as you can see in the tab, I am unable to check the checkbox to activate the module, it says some files are missing... I should have downloaded the stable version but I didn't know a module would be hard to remove once added.

this is the screenshot[image]

I went to `/admin/modules/uninstall` searched for this module but it's not there, and if I want to install a stable version from a zip file it says the module is already installed.

Usually on something like this, I would remove the file from `drupal\modules\paragraphs` however, I am not sure if this module has saved some configs in the database which will be left to stay if I physically remove the module by deleting it

Comment: But if I remove the files, how would I clean everything the module has so far saved in my database? Maybe the two versions of the module are different and if I installed the stable one, there might be something left from the dev version. ...

Comment: You're overthinking this. Files aren't missing - modules that it depends on are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The module is not installed, so can't be uninstalled.

To install you need to download/install its dependencies too, foremost the [entity_reference_revision](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_reference_revisions) module.

Comment: Yes, there are no missing files. The module just depends on another module to function.

Comment: Yeah, this! I can't believe I didn't see the requirements before trying to install this module, now only the first and third fields are able to be checked the "Paragraph Demo"  can not be checked still, and it says `(missing)Search_api (missing)ViewsTaxonomy`

Comment: Those are modules... you should probably be using Drush or Composer or Drupal Console to obtain modules because they will fetch dependencies listed in the info or Composer.json file.

Comment: I actually fetched the modules with composer when I created the drupal8 project, I think I will do the same for new addons

Comment: If you did that, you'd definitely have entity reference revisions.